# gRPC connectivity problem: How to figure out if it is the server or the client?

Tags: go, connection, grpc

I am reading a Golang book named "Go Blueprints". So one of the chapters is about implementing a micro-service. And the communication with that service could be http or gRPC. I think I did everything right, however I can't get gRPC communication work. When I try to ask the server from the client, I get this error:

```
rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service Vault
```

My question is how to start debugging this? How can I check if the problem is in the server or in the client?

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: Because I am not sure where the problem is, check out the whole project at https://github.com/avalchev94/go_blueprints/tree/master/vault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your implementation, the service name was wrong when you initialised endpoints for `Hash` and `Validate`. It should be `pb.Vault` instead of `Vault`. So the `New` method should look like this:

```
func New(conn *grpc.ClientConn) vault.Service {
    var hashEndpoint = grpctransport.NewClient(
        conn, "pb.Vault", "Hash",
        vault.EncodeGRPCHashRequest,
        vault.DecodeGRPCHashResponse,
        pb.HashResponse{},
    ).Endpoint()
    var validateEndpoint = grpctransport.NewClient(
        conn, "pb.Vault", "Validate",
        vault.EncodeGRPCValidateRequest,
        vault.DecodeGRPCValidateResponse,
        pb.ValidateResponse{},
    ).Endpoint()

    return vault.Endpoints{
        HashEndpoint:     hashEndpoint,
        ValidateEndpoint: validateEndpoint,
    }
}
```

In general, you should consult the generated `.pb.go` file of the matching `proto` on how things are named. As you can see, it is not straightforward and it probably depends on the implementation of the `proto` generators.

In your case, here is what it looks like:

```
grpc.ServiceDesc{
    ServiceName: "pb.Vault",
    HandlerType: (*VaultServer)(nil),
    Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
        {
            MethodName: "Hash",
            Handler:    _Vault_Hash_Handler,
        },
        {
            MethodName: "Validate",
            Handler:    _Vault_Validate_Handler,
        },
    },
    Streams:  []grpc.StreamDesc{},
    Metadata: "vault.proto",
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much! I am really thankful that you spend time finding that dumb issue.

Comment: No worries mate, glad to help :)

Comment: There are a few of typo in that book. Just got started and example was a beating. Had to resolve debug them with minimal understanding of everything going on. This resolution helps a lot in filling in the knowledge gap.